# using d3.json to access json data in a stored file

Tags: json, d3.js, console.log

I am new to d3.json, I am trying to access a file -> recordSet.json -> This is in the same folder as the html file

```
[
          { "module": "A", "errors": 50 },
          { "module": "B", "errors": 120 },
          { "module": "C", "errors": 10 },
          { "module": "D", "errors": 200 },
          { "module": "E", "errors": 27 },
          { "module": "F", "errors": 25 },
          { "module": "G", "errors": 40 }
];
```

in the html file I have the following code - the first line within the script tag is

```
d3.json("./recordSet.json", function (error, dataset) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        // code that works well for prewritten data
    }
}
```

json path - C:\Users\suchitrai.ext\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NodejsConsoleApp1\NodejsConsoleApp1\recordSet.json

html path - C:\Users\suchitrai.ext\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NodejsConsoleApp1\NodejsConsoleApp1\index.html

js file path - C:\Users\suchitrai.ext\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\NodejsConsoleApp1\NodejsConsoleApp1\app.js

And the console displays a SYNTAX ERROR ... I am not able to figure out what the error might be. The only line in the console says SyntaxError {} . When i do console.error(error) -> i get this 
SyntaxError {"Unexpected token m"} 
(anonymous function) 
event
respond

Comment: Put a screen shot of what you are seeing in the console. Did the recordSet.json load check in the browser network tab.

Comment: I am unable to upload an image.. bt it does check in the network .. but the status remains not modified - 304

Comment: Is it in the same folder as where you call it from ? If not use '../' to go back a folder

Comment: what is the path of your d3 `html file` and `json` file.

Comment: yes ..it is in the same folder.. and the path of html and json is the same.. as that of the js file that is using this..for a wrong path, it is giving a 'not found' error..here... it is only SYNTAX error

Comment: then replace `./recordSet.json` with just `recordSet.json`

Comment: yeah..tried it too.. with the same error

Comment: can you also add the complete console.log to your question and also the data in your recordSet.json

Comment: sorry, i didnt get u. wat do you want me to add?

Comment: I want you to add the complete error log that prints in your browser and also the data in your json.

Comment: i am not able to upload images due to proxy settings over here.

Comment: Remove that semicolon at the end of your JSON.

Comment: i tried ...its still d same..

Comment: replace `./recordSet.json` with `https://api.myjson.com/bins/547p0` and put an alert to `dataset` and let me know if you are still getting error and do you get anything in dataset .

Comment: hey siddP, thank u so much.. I got the output.. but,how did this happen?

Comment: well its not actually a solution you still have a problem. I just wanted to check rest of your code is working fine. So now the problem is still it is not able to find the file. Share the full path of json and html file in your question.

Comment: Are you running the files directly in browser on through a webserver and are you sure you have removed the `;` from the `recordSet.json` file.

Comment: yes.. i m running it through localhost, actually displaying a pie chart with these values... and I have removed the semicolon

Comment: Well then can't say much as the code looks fine to me it should work. Workaround how about resolving the data to a var instead of having a separate file. remove `d3.json("./recordSet.json", function (error, dataset) {` and replace with `dataset = [
          { "module": "A", "errors": 50 },
          { "module": "B", "errors": 120 },
          { "module": "C", "errors": 10 },
          { "module": "D", "errors": 200 },
          { "module": "E", "errors": 27 },
          { "module": "F", "errors": 25 },
          { "module": "G", "errors": 40 }
];`

Comment: I need to update data dynamically .. and I am using chrome.. cd that be a problem?

Comment: I think if data is coming dynamically then you don't an external file right and try one more thing move files from `C drive` and place it in some other drive may be `D` as sometimes browser don't have proper rights to access files in `C:`.

Comment: ok..thank you so much........i moved it to the D: drive and it worked like a charm....i m so glad.. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  per the discussion in comments the solution to above question is the files were placed in `C:` and browsers usually don't have enough permission to access files from system drives. Moving it to any other directory fixes the issue.